# Does convert between UIImage and CGImage is an heavy operation

Tags: ios

```
//sample 1
uIImage.cgImage

//sample 2
UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

In above code, sample 1 convert UIImage to CGImage, and sample 2 convert CGImage to UIImage.

---

**My question is:**

Does sample 1 and sample 2 is an heavy or light operation? 
If it just get the cgImage from UIImage or construct UIImage to wrap an CGImage?

Comment: As long as the asset hasn’t been purged due to memory pressure, the retrieval of the associated `CGImage` is not expensive. It’s generally the use of the image (which may trigger the decompressing of the asset) that is expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample: 1**

> If the image data has been purged because of memory constraints,
> invoking this method forces that data to be loaded back into memory.
> Reloading the image data may incur a performance penalty.

Please refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624159-cgimage

**Sample: 2**

Unfortunately, there are no documents available for the same.

But I have personally check conversion time duration for both sample 1 and 2 using below code.

```
//Image Size: 3 MB
let image = UIImage.init(named: "2.jpg")!    
print("Start Conversion: Image to CGImage",Date())
let cgImageSample = image.cgImage
print("End Conversion: Image to CGImage",Date())        
print("Start Conversion: CGImage to UIImage",Date())    
let imageConverted = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageSample!)
print("End Conversion:CGImage to UIImage",Date())
```

**Console Log:**

> Start Conversion: Image to CGImage 2019-03-18 05:17:02 +0000 End
>
> Conversion: Image to CGImage 2019-03-18 05:17:03 +0000 Start
>
> Conversion: CGImage to UIImage 2019-03-18 05:17:03 +0000 End
>
> Conversion:CGImage to UIImage 2019-03-18 05:17:04 +0000

**Conclusion:** Both operations were taken 1 second for conversion.

**Suggestion:** If you want to convert many images then it was heavy operation. If you want to convert a single image then it was not affecting performance too much.

Comment: Yep, though this is obviously only relevant when using `UIImage(named:)`. If you instantiated the image from a `Data`, `URL`, or built it programmatically, this does not apply.